# XML from URL - Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1 Why it works with one URL and not the other?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmldocument, xmlreader

As far as I can tell, these two end points are both valid XML output. However when I use the same code on the second end point I get the error:

> Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1

Here is my code:

```
        //Works
        XmlDocument testDocument = new XmlDocument();
        testDocument.Load("https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml");

        //Fails
        XmlDocument testDocumentTwo = new XmlDocument();
        testDocumentTwo.Load("https://www.domainNameHere.com/direct/umbraco/api/productsearch/NameSearch?countryCode=en-gb");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened Fiddler and watched the request and its response, and lo and behold your endpoint is returning JSON, not XML:

[image: Fiddler screenshot, showing result is JSON]

If I use `HttpClient` to set an explicit `Accept` header, then I get XML back and everything works:

```
using var client = new HttpClient();
var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://www.clinigengroup.com/direct/umbraco/api/productsearch/NameSearch?countryCode=en-gb");
requestMessage.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
var response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
var xml = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

XmlDocument testDocumentTwo = new XmlDocument();
testDocumentTwo.LoadXml(xml);
```

Comment: It is also not secure and returning http (not https).

Comment: @jdweng It's returning https for me...?

Comment: Really?  Look at the first line of the image you posted.

Comment: @jdweng The `HTTP/1.1`? That's used regardless of whether the connection is secured with TLS

Comment: I guess it depends on the server.  I usually see https.

Comment: @jdweng Are you sure? Do you have an example of a server which returns this? I've never seen that, and I can't find it in any RFCs